# Are all synonyms symmetrical?

Tags: synonyms

Do synonyms work both ways?

If "word A" is a synonym of "word B" does that means "word B" is a synonym of "word A"?

I suspect they are!

**EDIT:** *(Updating to cite sources as requested)*

I googled "are synonyms symmetrical" but [the results](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=are%20synonums%20symmetrica&oq=are%20synonums%20symmetrica&aqs=chrome..69i57.5265j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=are%20synonyms%20symmetrical) were skewed as the word "synonym" seems to be interpreted as if I'm looking for a synonym of the word "symmetrical".

Comment: Synonyms may share a high percentage of meaning/nuance/association,  but every word is different so they can never be 100% the same. It seems likely to me that there will be synonyms that work better one way round than the other...

Comment: Hello @Ev01, Please include in your question(s) any research conducted and cite sources. Ideally questions on English Language & Usage should reflect _some_ research effort.

Comment: No: see [transitivity/symetry of synonyms](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7pAIpz87jbEC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=synonym+transitivity&source=bl&ots=4w2qKpGI9l&sig=zfrGe-kCj_uwjx8gW1CUm3T3MHI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja_NLHxfLRAhUCvRoKHVeXBlQ4ChDoAQhIMAU#v=onepage&q=synonym%20transitivity&f=false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a study that looked at this. They looked at synonyms in a single thesaurus:

> The synonyms of a headword *w* are whatever words are listed in the entry for *w* in an on-line version of *The New Collins Thesaurus* (1984) (CT). According to the authors, "...no synonym is entered unless it is
>   *fully* substitutable for the headword in a sensible English sentence"

The paper reveals that the thesaurus has a lot of asymmetry:

> 62% [of synonymy links] are asymmetric (e.g., *part* has *department* as a synonym, but *department* does not have *part*)

They found several reasons for this asymmetry, most of which can be chalked up to omissions. However, a substantial portion of the asymmetry (18%) was due to hypernymy:

> For example, *book* lists *manual* as a synonym, but *manual* does not list *book*; instead special types of books such as *handbook* are given. This is because *book* is really a hypernym (not a synonym) of *manual*. Hypernym links are truly asymmetric in nature.
>   <sub>[A Tool for Investigating Tile Synonymy Relation in a Sense Disambiguated Thesaurus](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yael_Ravin/publication/2573121_A_Tool_For_Investigating_The_Synonymy_Relation_In_A_Sense_Disambiguated_Thesaurus/links/571e0ddf08aefa648899953b.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the thoughtful and accurate response! :)